# I am trying to integrate Jquery Combo-Tree Plugin into a Angular 6 Application

Tags: jquery-plugins, angular6

I am Facing this Error."Error: $(...).comboTree is not a function"

I have installed jquery,@types/jquery.
Add comboTree.js Plugin and  icontainer.js.

Stackblitz Url:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pg3hjd

Here My Code is

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import  $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

    ngOnInit() {
// SampleJSONData Be the Json with tree structure

var comboTree1, comboTree2;

$(document).ready(function($) {
 
 comboTree2 = $('#justAnotherInputBox').comboTree({
   source : SampleJSONData,
   isMultiple: false
  });
});
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <h3>Single Selection</h3>
   <input type="text" id="justAnotherInputBox" placeholder="Type to filter"/>
  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: comboTree is a plugin for jQuery. You need to install that too. I don't think it's on npm so you will have to download its js from their [github](https://github.com/kirlisakal/combo-tree) and import it in your app.component.ts

Comment: Yes, you are right.It's not having npm. Then how did you import the comboTree Plugin in app.component.ts

Comment: Getting Error cannot find module on import.In above I share the stackblitz link.

Comment: in your stackblitz comboTreePlugin.js is empty, there is nothing written in it. Make sure to download it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comboTree is a plugin for jQuery. You need to install that too. Download comboTreePlugin.js from their [github](https://github.com/kirlisakal/combo-tree) and add it to your project.
Then your your app.component.ts import it after importing jquery.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import  $ from 'jquery';
import '../comboTreePlugin';  // enter proper path here, depending where you saved the plugin in your project.

... rest of your code ...
```

Now open comboTreePlugin.js and import jquery there too:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
```

---

But editing vendor packages to import jquery in it is not something you should do. More elegant way to solve this problem is to:

1. Create a file called 'globals.js'(or whatever you wanna name it)
2. In it write this:

   ```
   import jquery from 'jquery';

   window.$ = jquery;
   window.jQuery = jquery;
   ```
3. Now in your app.component.ts your imports should look like this:

   ```
   import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import './globals';
   import '../comboTreePlugin';

   ... rest of your code ...
   ```
4. It should be working now, no need to edit anything in comboTreePlugin.js

   No need to import jquery in your component now as importing globals will bring both `$` and `jQuery` to scope.

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qswozq
https://angular-qswozq.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thanks,You Save the day.

Comment: ah, its alright, you will get reputation eventually